# error in python setting method for callbacks

Tags: python, class, websocket

I try to define a Class in python for managing WebSockets, this [docu-example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/) is what am using

this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import websocket
import thread
import time

class WebSocket:
    def on_message1(self, ws, message):
        print message

    def on_error1(self, ws, error):
        print error

    def on_close1(self, ws):
        print "Socket Closed"

    def start(self):
        global ws
        ws.run_forever()

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://" + host+":"+port,
                                        on_message = on_message1,
                                        on_error = on_error1,
                                        on_close = on_close1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Error: create an instance of this class instead!"
```

But when I run the code I get the error:

> File "/home/pi/ABC/CASCADE/WebSocketClientClass.py", line 37, in **init**
>
> NameError: global name 'on_message1' is not defined
>   it is defined but somehow is not working... why?

thanks

Comment: No, it's not. You need to use `self.on_message1`. Same for the rest...

Comment: Also, I see no need for a `class`. Python != Java. Just use functions, like in your link. Indeed, I believe you may be shadowing a class in `websocket`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the method inside the class WebSocket, so to access it, you need `self`, like this :

```
self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://" + host+":"+port,
                                    on_message = self.on_message1,
                                    on_error = self.on_error1,
                                    on_close = self.on_close1))
```